# How can I link lots of JS files into one main file, which I can refence in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have spent a lot of time watching videos and creating almost a library, similar to p5.js (I watch quite a lot of Dan Shiffman) and I've got lots of files for different things. I have an init.js, dom.js, drawing.js, and so on. Right now, whenever I make a new project, I link all of the files in the order I need them to load in the HTML file, but that takes up a lot of lines and it just looks clunky.

I want to know if there's a way I can make one main file called 'library.js' and link all of the other files with the utility functions and constants and variables in, make sure they're in order, and then just use one reference to the library file in my index.html. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If all the files need to be included, you either need to:

- include them all like you are already doing (easiest)
- Put all the file contents into a single file (bad code practice and messy)
- Run a script to build and bundle multiple files into one!

I recommend this last one, however it does add some complexity and a build step that you do not currently have. [ESBuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) is a great option

`npm i esbuild --save`

Then create a new file like this, named `build.js` for example

```
import * as esbuild from 'esbuild';

/**
 * @typedef {esbuild.BuildOptions}
 */
export const esBuildOptions = {
  stdin: { contents: '' },
  allowOverwrite: true,
  bundle: true,
  minify: true,
  inject: [
    'init.js',
    'dom.js',
    'drawing.js',
  ],
  outfile: 'library.js',
};

await esbuild.build(esBuildOptions);
```

run `node build.js` and it will should combine and minify your files into `library.js` or whatever you want to call it